# How to make an element NOT to steal focus from an input?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I have a simple input and an SVG-pic that sends the input-text to a server and instantly adds the text into a document.createElement('div')...etc

Is there a way to make my SVG-pic non-focusable so it doesn't steal focus from others (in my case - my input)

upd.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>
            <input id="senderInput" type="text">
            <img src="../../img/Calendar.svg" alt="" onclick="imgClick(event)">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
        .wrapper {
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .wrapper > div {
            width: 250px;
            height: 150px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: var(--divBG);
            margin: 20px;
        }
```

```js
        arr = ['#f00', '#aaa004', '#b70808', '#0855b7', '#681a73', '#d56e00']

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper > div').forEach(d => {
                d.style.backgroundColor = arr[getRandomInt(6)]
            })
            
        });

        function j(arg) {
            return document.querySelector(arg)
        }

        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        }

        function imgClick(e) {
            j('.wrapper > div').innerText = j('#senderInput').value
            setTimeout(() => {
                var dd = document.createElement('div')
                dd.style.backgroundColor = arr[getRandomInt(6)]
                dd.innerText = '234'
                j('.wrapper').appendChild(dd)
            }, 100);
            j('#senderInput').focus()
        }
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If clicking on the pic sends the input-text to a server as you say, you definitely shouldn't try to prevent it from getting focus (because of accessibility reasons)

Comment: What you can do is add a key (down/up/pressed) listener to the img and delegate the events (multiple ways you can do this) to the input field

Comment: If I add a key listener, how do I trigger it? By sending it manually with js after sending a request to a server?
I mean, I send the input value by clicking on the svg, so when does the key-event happen?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simple

```js
event.preventDefault()
msgInput.focus()
```

worked fine, the problem solved